Qt5: "socket notifiers cannot be disabled from another thread" issue
I am also facing a similar issue I have a C++ Qt application built on Qt4 and all QTcpSocket implementation was working as expected when I migrated to Qt5 I got this issue:
socket notifiers cannot be disabled from another thread


Hard to tell without code, but you're probably calling waitForRead from other thread that your QTcpSocket was instantiated, which is forbidden.
You have two options to fix this situation

Use async api only (readyRead) in gui thread (waitForRead freezes application and therefore undesirable))

Instantiate QTcpSocket in separate thread and use any api (waitForRead freezes thread which is reasonable), but only in this thread, pass data to main thread over signal-slot mechanism


